# woocommerce import order with custom order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to import an orders file with a custom order status.

Code for new custom status:

```
register_post_status(
    'wc-cc-shipping',
    array(
        'label'                     => 'CC Awaiting shipping',
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'CC shipping (%s)', 'CC shipping (%s)' ),
    )
);
```

On the site, everything works as excepted.

but when I'm trying to import a csv file with this custom order status, it does not recognize this order status.

So my first question is, is it possible to import with different order statuses?

and if it is possible, what status name do I need to point in my csv file? to the `wc-cc-shipping` (like in the example)?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is possible to use custom order status. I am guessing you've not added your custom status in the WooCommerce order statuses list using `wc_order_statuses` filter hook and some kind of validation is failing because of that. So I will suggest following this [article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-woocommerce-custom-order-status/) add your custom order status to the list. then check if it solves the issue or not.

Comment: If that doesn't solve then you can try using `cc-shipping` as a status value. I am totally unsure about the option name during import but you can test that out and see the results.

Comment: Actually i did use wc_order_statuses also but maybe it depend on the import configuration.